# How to install jmeter server agent in a server hosted in k8cluster

Tags: user-interface, jmeter, containers

I am trying to collect perfmon results from jmeter and installed perfmon plugin in my jmeter.
What are the steps should i needed to do to install server agent to pod or host in k8cluster ?

I went into the pod using Kubectl and checked its Yaml.
But i don't know how I would install this server agent in the Pod.

Answer (score 0):

The pod is being created on the basis of a [Container](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container/)

So you basically need to add some steps to the image to wit:

1. Install [Java runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Java_Runtime_Environment)
2. Install [Server Agent](http://jmeterplugins.com/wiki/PerfMonAgent/index.html) using `./startAgent.sh` script provided
3. Run the server agent
4. Expose port 4444 (or other one if you want to customize it) in pod YAML

Example [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) would be something like:

```
FROM alpine:3.19.0

RUN apk add openjdk11-jre-headless unzip wget

RUN wget https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/releases/download/2.2.3/ServerAgent-2.2.3.zip

RUN unzip ServerAgent-2.2.3.zip

WORKDIR ServerAgent-2.2.3

ENTRYPOINT ["./startAgent.sh"]
```

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)